# How to import a URL in react with useEffect

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

How do I do this on react? Importing a URL in react with `useEffect`. Am I doing it right?

HTML

```
    // <style type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
    //     @import url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.freshdesk.com/widget/freshwidget.css); 
    // </style>
```

React

```
useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
  
    script.src = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.freshdesk.com/widget/freshwidget.csss";
    script.type = "text/css";
    script.media = "screen, projection"
    script.async = true;
  
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    }

}, []);
```

Comment: Have you considered [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet)?

Comment: There's (probably) a typo in your URL, https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.freshdesk.com/widget/freshwidget.csss should be https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.freshdesk.com/widget/freshwidget.css

Comment: You are trying to importing CSS using a script tag. You should be using `document.createElement('link')` and add the `rel="stylesheet"` attribute.